# Design rationale for time(2)

Tags: posix, api-design

> If `tloc` is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed to by `tloc`.

Question: Why would one like to store the value somewhere else than in the return value? Is this some kind of historical relic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a relic:

> The `tloc` argument is obsolescent and should always be NULL in new code.

But this raises the question why it was designed that way in the first place.

Comment: My guess is that `tloc` as was the original sole mechanism due to ancient typeless pre-K&R C assuming all functions to return 16-bit native integers/pointers, with a 32-bit return value added along with improved support for long integers and K&R-style return-value function signatures yet with `tloc` still kept around for backward compatibility. I am rather hazy on the early development history though, so you probably want to dig around in the old UNIX sourcecode archives for clues.